# Predict parameters of another model

Tags: r, experiment-design, model, functional-data-analysis

I would like to make a model to predict the parameters of another model.

As example,
By using design of experiment I made some trials and I measured the temperature (response).
e.g.

```
library(AlgDesign) 

cand_list = expand.grid(
            A = c('b', 'f'),   B = c(0, 1.5, 3),   C = c(2, 7)) 

doe_grid <- optFederov(Temprature ~ A + B + C, 
            data = cand_list, nTrials = 12, crit="D")$design
doe_grid$Temprature <- NA
```

However, I measured the temperature through time so I have multiple responses per treatment. Now, from each treatment of my DoE I have a trend that looks like the one below (you can't see the trendline because the data points hide it. It's like 100% fit).

[image]

At this example the formula is 7584x^2 +2317.2x + 46.767 and is result of the 1st treatment from my DoE.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to build a model so as to predict these parameters of the formula (7584x^2 +2317.2x + 46.767).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you add some more details? But it seems your response really is a **function**, so  maybe add the tag [tag:functional-data-analysis] and read up on that?

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen, do you think that could be approached with the GAM as well? I had a look on FDA you suggested and it looks like should be a solution however, it looks more complicated to understand too.